# Adding extra auth parameter to client credentials grant type in Ballerina?

Tags: authentication, ballerina, ballerina-http

I need to send a request like the one below.

```
curl --request POST --url https://dev-jlsubxnitkpok2tw.au.auth0.com/oauth/token 
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{"client_id":"","client_secret":"","audience":"","grant_type":"client_credentials"}'
```

I am using Ballerina like below

```
http:Client securedEP = check new ("http://postman-echo.com", {
            auth: {
                tokenUrl: "xxx/oauth/token",
                clientId: "xxx",
                clientSecret: "xxx",
                scopes: ["read", "submit"]
            }
        }
```

I get an error like the one below from the service.

```
cause: Failed to get a success response from the endpoint. Response code: '403'. 
Response body: '{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"No audience 
parameter was provided, and no default audience has been configured"}'
```

How can I achieve this in Ballerina?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `optionalParams` parameter in [ClientCredentialsGrantConfig](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/oauth2/2.4.1/records/ClientCredentialsGrantConfig) to specify that.

```
http:Client securedEP = check new ("http://postman-echo.com", {
        auth: {
            tokenUrl: "xxx/oauth/token",
            clientId: "xxx",
            clientSecret: "xxx",
            scopes: ["read", "submit"],
            optionalParams: {
                "audience": "aud"
            }
        }
    });
```

Note that the `auth` record field here is coming from [CommonClientConfiguration](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/http/2.4.3/records/CommonClientConfiguration) type.